Transpile not working properly for decomposing single qubit gates into Rx Ry and Rz
I used the above code to decompose hadamard gate into RxRyRz but i am getting wrong angles which on multiplying don't match hadamard gate . Interestingly when i am using inbuilt hadamard hate using q.h(0) i am getting correct answer. Please help to find out what is going wrong
Code in text form:
    import numpy as np
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
    from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
    import math

    custom_gate_matrix = (1/math.sqrt(2))*np.array([[1, 1],
                         [1, -1]]
    custom_gate = Operator(custom_gate_matrix)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
    qc.unitary(custom_gate, [0], label='custom_gate')
    // qc.h(0)
    //print(qc.unitary(custom_gate, [0], label='custom_gate'))
    decomposed_circuit = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['rx', 'ry', 
    'rz'])

    rx_angle = 0
    ry_angle = 0
    rz_angle = 0

    for instr, qargs, _ in decomposed_circuit.data:
        if instr.name == 'rx':
            rx_angle = instr.params[0]
        elif instr.name == 'ry':
            ry_angle = instr.params[0]
        elif instr.name == 'rz':
            rz_angle = instr.params[0]

    print("Rx angle:", rx_angle)
    print("Ry angle:", ry_angle)
    print("Rz angle:", rz_angle)


This is because a global phase is added during circuit transpilation.

A better option is to use OneQubitEulerDecomposer to get the angles.
from qiskit.synthesis import OneQubitEulerDecomposer

basis = 'ZYZ'
angles = OneQubitEulerDecomposer(basis).angles(custom_gate_matrix)
print(angles)

You will get same values of you do the same with H-gate
from qiskit.circuit.library import HGate

angles = OneQubitEulerDecomposer(basis).angles(HGate().to_matrix())
print(angles)


Thanks for answering but I want my basis to be RxRyRz which is not supported by OneQubitEulerDecomposer
